# How to remove the background image in iFrame : Android

Tags: android, iframe, android-webview

I am loading a video coming from video provider but I keep on seeing a random image (gray play icon image) in the background. How do I remove that image.

This is the code that I am using

```html
<html><body style="margin:0px"><iframe id="vzvd-6794570" name="vzvd-6794570" title="vzaar video player" class="vzaar-video-player" type="text/html" width="100%" height="350px"frameborder="0" allowFullScreen allowTransparency="true" mozallowfullscreen webkitAllowFullScreen src="http://view.vzaar.com/6794570/player"></iframe></body></html>
```

[image: So you can see that there is a gray play button background in the picture]

[image: Also happening here on portrait mode]

Answer (score 0):

use css :

```
<iframe style="background-image:none" ... ></ifram>
```